# Footer stays at the bottom of the browser but not under the content

Tags: css, position, footer

So it seems I'm having two problems from two differnt approaches trying to get the footer right.
Using `position: abslotute;` will make the footer stay at the bottom of the browser, but not under the content. So when you open the webpage you will see the footer at the bottom, but when you scroll down to see the rest of the content, it will remain in the position it was found (which is overlaping a div).
So I tried `clear: both;` which doesn't work with the combo of `position: absolute;`, that makes the footer go under the content, but it will remain under there and not at the actual bottom of the page. 
How do I finally sort this footer out, keeping it at the bottom of the page even with different screen size and under the content?

Here's my HTML and CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: arial;
}
nav {
  height: 60px;
  background: #dfd9d3;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0px;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #d9d1c7;
}
#indexContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#Banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border-bottom: solid 4px orange;
}
#backgroundBanner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#backgroundBanner img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-40%);
}
#logoBanner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 498px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  text-align: center;
}
#logoBanner img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
}
#sloganBanner {
  border-top: solid white 3px;
  border-bottom: solid white 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 425px;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#indexSlogan {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}
#indexBottom {
  width: 100%;
}
#indexTitleB {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#indexH2Title {
  width: 400px;
  border-bottom: solid black 2px;
  margin: 7px auto;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#indexLeftB {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
#indexRightB {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.indexH2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}
indexBImage {
  width: 281px;
  border: solid black 5px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.indexImage {
  width: 280px;
  height: auto;
}
.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  clear: both;
}
.indexContent {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <nav>
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a id="active" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="indexContent">

      <div id="Banner">
        <div id="backgroundBanner">
          <img src="">
        </div>
        <div id="logoBanner">
          <img src="">
        </div>
        <div id="sloganBanner">
          <h1 id="indexSlogan">Some text text text text text text</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="indexBottom">
        <div id="indexTitleB">
          <h2 id="indexH2Title">Some text</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="indexLeftB">
          <div class="indexBTitle">
            <h2 class="indexH2">Some text</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="indexBText">
            <p class="indexP">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
              <br>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText <a href="#">Text</a> TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText.
              <br>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="indexBImage">
            <img src="" class="indexImage">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="indexRightB">
          <div class="indexBTitle">
            <h2 class="indexH2">Some Text</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="indexBText">
            <p class="indexP">Some Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text TextTextText
              <br>Some Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
          </div>
          <div class="indexBImage">
            <img src="" class="indexImage">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <footer>
    </footer>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: did my answer below help you? Please let me know your feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Not really, I was getting the same problem I initially had....please look at my solution I have posted, I found what I wanted. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

After many hours and many web pages of searching for a footer that stays at the bottom of the content and page without using position: fixed; I present you the solution: http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/
If you have overflowing content, simply add a new div inside your container/wrapper div with this:

```
#footerSpacing { clear: both; height: 80px;
```

The height will seperate the footer and the content. And clear: both will ensure nothing overlaps that div.